# Some questions about Hartshorne's exercise II.3.17 (b)~(c) Zariski space

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have some questions while trying to solve 'Exercise II 3.17(a)~(c), Hartshorne.

**Zariski Space**: A topological space $X$ is called a **Zariski space** if it is [Noetherian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noetherian_topological_space) and every (nonempty) closed irreducible subsets has a unique generic point(Ex2.9)...

$~~~~~~~$(b) Show that any minimal nonempty closed subset of a Zariski space consists of one point.

$~~~~~~~$(c) Show that a Zariski space $X$ satisfies the axiom $T_0$: given any two distinct points of X, there is an open set containing $~~~~~~~$one but not the other.

I roughly sketched the proof of (b) and (c). I wonder whether my sketch is right or not...

Exercise (b) : Since $X$ is a Zariski space, $X$ has notherian, thus for **every** sequence $Y_1 \supset Y_2 \supset.... \supset $ for closed subsets , there exists closed an integer $r$ s.t $Y_r=Y_{r+1}=...$

**Claim**  : $Y_r$ should be a singleton set [?]

If my claim is right, for any closed subset $K$ is given, by letting $K=K_1$, by the definition of Noetherian, we always make a descending chain and the smallest closed set of the given chain is a singleton set.

Exercise (c) : If the statement (b) is true, since a singleton set is closed, choose different points $p,q \in X$, then $X-\left \{ p \right \}$  is an open subset which contains $q$ but does not contain $p$.

Comment: Your sketch for (b) doesn't explain how you choose the $Y_i$ in order to get your desired conclusion, which is the real meat of the problem. Next, your claim that "a singleton set is closed" for part (c) is completely false, so you'll need to dramatically alter your strategy here.

Answer (score 1):

For part (b), as KReiser said, you don't explain how $Y_r$ is a singleton, which you must do! In fact, there are Noetherian topological spaces which are not $T_0,$ so your strategy will need more juice to be able to work! Consider for example the space $X = \{a,b\}$ with the indiscrete topology. This is clearly Noetherian, as there are only two closed subsets, but there is no open set containing exactly one of $a$ and $b$.

**Hint for (b):** Instead of using the Noetherian condition here, try using the other condition, that every nonempty irreducible closed subset has a unique generic point. Start by letting $Y$ be a minimal nonempty closed subset, and let $y\in Y.$ Now, what can you say about $\overline{\{y\}}$ and what does this imply about $Y$?

Again, as KReiser says, singleton sets need not be closed. An example of a Zariski space is $\{x,\eta\}$, with open sets $\emptyset,\{\eta\},$ and $\{x,\eta\}.$ Then you can see that $\{\eta\}$ is not closed!

**Hint for (c):** Again, try using the generic point condition. Let $x,y\in X$ be distinct points. What happens if $y\in\overline{\{x\}}$? What happens if $y\not\in\overline{\{x\}}$?

**Bigger hint:** Don't look until you're thought hard about the above!

> For any point $x,$ $\overline{\{x\}}$ is irreducible.